# Can not create liferay project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I want to create liferay project in eclipse , I  run liferay sdk successfully. Now i want to create a new project .

I am using

1. kepler eclipse
2. java 7

When i create a new project i get this error :

> MESSAGE NoSuchMethodError: com.liferay.ide.core.ILiferayProjectProvider.createNewProject(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;

Can anyone tell me how can resolve this error or can create project by alternative method.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Liferay 6.2, despite tagging with the liferay-6 tag.

It looks like you have some fragments of Liferay-IDE installed in addition to your IDE installation. I'd suggest to either download the full Liferay-IDE or connect to its update site and update the installation. In case this doesn't work already, report back and make sure to include the version of Liferay-IDE that you're using as well.